# is there a way to keep index of listbox while sorting items?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, listbox

I'm using listbox to get items from xml file, and each item has an id, name and content,
but i put in listbox just names and i store other data in variable like dictionary(of integer : index, string : names), and keep relation between items in listbox with items in dictionary, everything is good for now, but if i sort items (after modification of names) in listbox it loses index ordering, :(

before sort!

listbox ---------------------------------- dictionary ---------------

index | value -------------------------- key | value

0 | admin ------------------------------ 0 | admin
1 | adam.ley -------------------------- 1 | adam.ley
2 | jean.clift --------------------------- 2 | jean.clift

change adam.ley to zero, and sort the list!!

0 | admin ------------------------------ 0 | admin
1 | jean.clift --------------------------- 1 | zero
2 | zero -------------------------------- 2 | jean.clift

thank you everybody :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to make a class of the item.

having more than one details.
like

class would be say "MyItem" having the members
  (integer id,
  string name,
  string content)

this would be the class structure and add this item(class) to the list box
it is possible in c# there must be something like this in vb.net

for further reference check this link and get a hint.
[Using ListBox to store multiple pieces of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262118/using-listbox-to-store-multiple-pieces-of-data)

Answer (score 1):

So after i create a class as following :

```
Public Class ListItem

    Private _Id As Integer
    Private _Name As String

    ' Initialize the object.
    Public Sub New(ByVal Id As Integer, ByVal Name As String)
        _Id = Id
        _Name = Name
    End Sub

    ' Return the object's Name.
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _Name
    End Function

    ' Return the object's Id.
    Public Function Id() As Integer
        Return _Id
    End Function

End Class
```

To Add new Item to listbox :

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Id, Name))
```

and it works perfectly :)!

but what i need is to get the index of an item that have the Id = 3 for example!!

thanks everybody! have a nice day ;)